# Converting Serial input to Keyboard Button-press

Tags: java, serial-port, usb, keyboard-shortcuts, converters

Not sure if I'm asking this question on the correct site (I have been wondering if this should rather be posted on the EE.stackoverflow site).

So I have an OLD serial input mouse, and I want the system to reprogram or retranslate it to a keyboard button-press.

The whole thing is that I have software with shortcut keys, but remembering all of them is just not possible. So, why does one want to have a whole keyboard when one can only have a set of three buttons? Using a keyboard, when one presses F11 (and holds it in), it activates the system's mic. While holding in F11, one wants to press F1 to start playing music, thus being a voice over song application.

I've been trying to research the possibility, and I've come to notice that there are a LOT of applications that can convert a USB device, such as a game controller to a keyboard button-press. That's what's driving my concept.

Is this even possible?

Thanks,
Johan Brink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/562972/how-to-map-bind-mouse-button-as-keyboard-button-in-windows-7), if you are using Windows, you can use X-Mouse Button Control for mouse. If you want to use gamepad, try [J2K - A Joystick to Keyboard Mapper 1.1](http://www.emulation-evolved.net/?q=node/19)

Comment: You, kind sir, are my hero. That's precisely what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on Makey Makey  (www.makeymakey.com). This is a board which emulates a key stroke each time one of his input is closed.

Comment: $50 for a button? Johan mentioned that he wanted to use some scrap hardware to make something cheap and simple.

Comment: The cheap button is just the visible part of the iceberg. Some electronic to interface it with your computer is also needed. It this was as simple as you seem to think, Johan wouldn't ask, would he ?  :-)